# Box under a string text

Tags: math-mode, graphics, table-of-contents

I want to do a dollar sign text that looks like this:

[image]

I already have this:

```
$$\underline{a}\;\underline{a}\;\underline{a}...\underline{a}\;\underline{b}...\underline{b}$$
```

How can I put the box things under the lines?

Comment: Welcome! Never use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: I am not sure that it is LaTeX.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\underbracket` with `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\[
\underbracket[0.4pt][3ex]{
  \smash[b]{\,\underbracket[0.4pt]{
    \,\underline{a}\ \underline{a}\ \underline{a}\ \dots\ \underline{a}\,
  }_{k}}
  \ \underline{b}\ \dots\ \underline{b}\,
}_n
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 For `\underbracket` - never used it!